# Save Mongo/Mongoose Object within another Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I have a Mongo object that looks like this:

```
var foodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:      { type: String, required: false, unique: true },
   image:     { type: String, required: false, unique: true },
});
```

The idea is to be able to save a "food" object to a user. (The data comes from a seed file.)

**So if the data going into the model above was:**

```
name: tacos, 
image: tacos.gif
```

What I want to be able to do is **then save that data to a user model.** 
Is the best way to go about this to have a field in the user model to save the data? (Saving to last two fields) Such as:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    foodName1: String,
    foodImage1: String, 
});
```

To me this seems like I'm saving the data twice, within two difference models. Is this the correct way to handle this? Or **is there a better way to store the food data inside the user's model**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can replace  foodName1: String, foodImage1: String by :

```
food: {id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'foodSchema'}
```

and after when u retrieve foodSchema use populate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

if you need more than one foodSchema

```
food: [{id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'foodSchema'}]
```

for save juste create food object and put on existing user or new created user:

```
let user = new UserSchema({'user info here'})
let food = new foodSchema({name: 'test',image: 'test'});
user.food = food
user.save().then(() => {

})
```

or for push a food in a food array on existing user:

```
UserSchema.findById(req.body.id).exec((err, docc) => {
                docc.food.push(food)
                docc.save((err, result) => {
                    if (err)
                        res.sendStatus(500);
                    res.sendStatus(200);
                })
            })
```

otherwise we can just add the _id of the food object, but it's less visual

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome. Any chance you could give an example of how to save data using that set up?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!!

Comment: It's a pleasure to help, it's always hard to start a new thing